# Please clarify table vs query based On Conflict clauses in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, database-design, transactions, conflict

I've been reading about SQLite conflict resolution and I'm not totally sure about one aspect.

If I have
`PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT IGNORE` as part of the table, do I still need to put `INSERT OR IGNORE` on an Insert query to have it ignore conflicts, or will it pick up on that from the table definition?

Something I read said something about table definitions only affecting operations on the whole table, but I am not sure that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider testing that before asking the question?

```
sqlite> create table test (id integer primary key on conflict ignore);
sqlite> insert into test values (1);
sqlite> insert into test values (1);
sqlite> insert into test values (1);
sqlite> insert into test values (1);
sqlite> select * from test;
1

sqlite> drop table test;
sqlite> create table test (id integer primary key);
sqlite> insert into test values (1);
sqlite> insert into test values (1);
Error: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
sqlite> insert or ignore into test values (1);
sqlite> insert or ignore into test values (1);
sqlite> select * from test;
1
```